# Watering clover seeds

Tags: lawn, watering, seeds, clover

I'm planting some Dutch white clover in my yard from seed. The seeds came already inoculated. We generally have weeks where it rains several times a day for at least a week during the spring, can I just sow the seeds and let them sit for a week or two until we get a lot of rain, or is there some risk of either drying out the seeds or having the inoculant damaged by heat/dryness?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I planted Palestine Strawberry clover in my yard (Phoenix, AZ) this past fall. My clover seems extraordinarily resilient so far (with the exception of falling prey to our local quail population). Considering clover is considered a difficult-to-remove lawn pest by many, I don't expect you'll have too much trouble getting them established.

When I sowed mine, I covered them in a thin layer of composted mulch to retain moisture. Since it's dry out here (read: no rain for three months), I did water every day to keep it moist. Provided you get a good ground-soaking with rain and you mulch, you may not need to water that much (if at all).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of light mulching to keep it damp - I am going to give it a try.